# Detect cause of failing rename

Tags: go

I use some code similar to the lines below. The rename can fail if the directory is blocked because some application has a file open in it.

```
err := os.Rename("C:/temp/inUse", "c:/temp/Renamed")

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    ...
}
```

I am able to detect this fact when I check `err` for this content:

> rename C:/temp/inUse c:/temp/Renamed: Der Prozess kann nicht auf die
>   Datei zugreifen, da sie von einem anderen Prozess verwendet wird.

(which translates to "The process is unable to access the file because it is used by a different process")
But this message varies depending on the OS language.

Is it possible to detect the problem by a unique "error code" ? I wouldn't mind if the solution is specific to Windows and doesn't work on other operating systems supported by Go.

Ideally I could do something like `if err.Err == 32 { fmt.Println( "Your directory is in use please ...`

Comment: I am doubtful you'll be able to get more details out of the `err` in Go. However, if I were experiencing this problem I would use a tool like perfmon to figure out what was locking the file and then try to address it outside of my application code - or possibly with a code change - but if two separate applications are sharing file resources you have to coordinate them using something external to both programs like writing a lock file. My cursory glance over Go's `os` package tells me there is nothing to give you this info directly.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Thanks for your Input. I know how to use sysinternals to find out which process causes the problem. My goal is to detect the cause and give the user a hint what could cause the problem

Comment: If you have something you can run from the command line then you can us Go's exec library ( https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/ ) to invoke it from your app, read the output from std.out, parse out the list of other apps locking the file and then display it to the user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error returned by `os.Rename` is of type [`*os.LinkError`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#LinkError) which gives you access to the underlying error from the operating system. You should be able to use that to distinguish the particular error you are encountering.

You'll need to convert the error to *os.LinkError first.

For instance, trying to rename a folder (`/Users/t/pprof`) to another name that is write-protected (`/Users/t/pprof2`):

```
func TestRename(t *testing.T) {
    err := os.Rename("/Users/t/pprof", "/Users/t/pprof2")
    if err != nil {
        e := err.(*os.LinkError)
        t.Logf("Op: ", e.Op)
        t.Logf("Old: ", e.Old)
        t.Logf("New: ", e.New)
        t.Logf("Err: ", e.Err)
    }
}
```

Provides the following output:

```
Op: %!(EXTRA string=rename)
Old: %!(EXTRA string=/Users/t/pprof)
New: %!(EXTRA string=/Users/t/pprof2)
Err: %!(EXTRA syscall.Errno=operation not permitted)
```

The OS error code is accessible as the `Err` member, but will be different depending on the OS you are running.

The `Err` member is of type [`syscall.Errno`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Errno). To further inspect the actual error, you need to convert it to that type first:

```
oserr := e.Err.(syscall.Errno)
```

Now `oserr` can be compared with the values for `Errno` declared in the [`syscall`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/) package. You'll find them if you search for `ENOENT` on that page.

For instance, you can check for your particular error by doing:

```
switch oserr {
    case syscall.ENOENT:
        // Handle this error
    default:
        // Handle other errors
    }
}
```

In general, it's very convenient to use fmt.Printf when debugging these sort of issues. In the example above:

```
fmt.Println(err)
```

prints

```
rename /Users/t/pprof /Users/t/pprof2: operation not permitted
```

where-as

```
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", err)
```

prints

```
&os.LinkError{Op:"rename", Old:"/Users/t/pprof", New:"/Users/t/pprof2", Err:0x1}
```

giving details on the actual error, and not just its string representation.

Comment: Thanks, these are the internals I was searching for. Unfortunately I don't understand the part where `testing.T` comes from. How can I call this ?

Comment: The testing.T variable is part of the go test framework. It's very helpful for writing quick unit tests for testcases like this. You can just remove the method signature and replace t.Logf with fmt.Printf for similar functionality without the test framework.

Comment: Thanks, but I only manage to retrieve the text (which is OS locale specific) from `Err` but fail to get the underlying value. In my scenario (I already tested with your example) I retrieve `&os.LinkError{Op:"rename", Old:"C:/temp/inUse", New:"c:/temp/Renamed", Err:0x20}` but when I access `Err` I get `Der Prozess kann nicht auf die Datei zugreifen,...` which is the translation of  `0x20`. But I need the _raw_ value. Do you have an idea how to retrieve `0x20` without running a regex on the whole string ?

Comment: I've updated the answer with details on how to inspect the error further. Hopefully this will get you on the right track.

Comment: You certainly did ;-) I was missing the part where the error is converted to syscall. Now everything is working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Go 1.13, if you just want to check if the underlying error is of a specific type you can do:

```go
err := os.Rename("C:/temp/inUse", "c:/temp/Renamed")

if err != nil && errors.Is(err, syscall.EEXIST) {
    fmt.Println("File already exists")
    ...
}
```

You can read more about error handling in Go 1.13 on [the official Golang blog](https://blog.golang.org/go1.13-errors).